wrong number of arguments specified for '__deprecated__' attribute
I'm trying to compile newlib 3.0.0 for target m68k-aout I've already got binutils and gcc for the target built I'm building it with gcc-13.3.0, But I'm getting these two errors.
newlib-3.0.0/newlib/libc/include/stdlib.h:130: error: wrong number of arguments specified for '__deprecated__' attribute
newlib-3.0.0/newlib/libc/include/stdlib.h:138: error: wrong number of arguments specified for '__deprecated__' attribute

Are there any workarounds or fixes I could try?

The error message is pretty explicit:
Your (old!) version of newlib uses __deprecated__ incorrectly.
The source code is:
#if __BSD_VISIBLE || (__XSI_VISIBLE >= 4 && __POSIX_VISIBLE < 200112)
char *  mktemp (char *) _ATTRIBUTE ((__deprecated__("the use of `mktemp' is dangerous; use `mkstemp' instead")));

GCC starting with version 3.0.1 only supports a __deprecated__ attribute without arguments.
So, this code doesn't work on any GCC of the last 23 years (!!); however, that's not a problem, because all of these support POSIX-2001, so that this never gets compiled, normally.
However, you seem to be porting an old version of newlib using a new compiler to a target where that might not be the case.
So, first recommendation would be to use a newer newlib. Newlib is pretty API-stable, it's a libc after all, so that might be pretty straightforward. Maybe that already solves the issue.
Then, check whether __BSD_VISIBLE gets set (newlib/libc/include/sys/features.h), or whether __XSI_VISIBLE gets set and why then GCC 13 from 2023/2024 thinks it's not even POSIX-2001. (is maybe something in your code setting _SVID_SOURCE? m68k-aout sounds suspiciously much like you're targeting obsolete machines?)

I think m68k-aout might be a cross-compiler for embedded microcontrollers such as MC68332 and therefore potentially off-topic for Unit and Linux, since are targeting a microcontroller too small to run Unix or Linux.

@ChesterGillon au contraire! newlib is a libc that contains a POSIX subsystem. And there's microcontroller operating systems whose design goals are POSIX compliance, e.g. NuttX; and even a 25 years old Motorola 68302 would not have stood pale next to many a system running, say, UNIX SVR4. However, I see it less about the target, but the build machine here; and that seems to be a Linux or similar.

m68k-aout is obsolete it was removed in binutils 2.31 and gcc 4.4 and I'm just trying to compile the toolchain so I can update an old version of a homebrew  jaguar SDK. and I've tried using an updated version of newlib and I got
newlib-4.4.0.20231231/newlib/libc/include/sys/_intsup.h:71:2: error: #error "Unable to determine type definition of intptr_t"
newlib-4.4.0.20231231/newlib/libc/include/sys/_intsup.h:78:2: error: #error "Unable to determine type definition of int32_t"
